# Limit on comment (hasMany relation with Post model) for each post in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to limit on hasMany relation in laravel but instead of each post it limit on whole or all records. Below is my code for explanation.

```
 class Post extends Model {


    protected $table = "user_posts";
    protected $appends = ['logged_in_user_id', 'comments_count'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->take(2);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get 2 or 3 recent comment on each post as below

```
$posts = \App\Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->with('comments')->where('user_posts.user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
```

Problem is instead of giving 2 comment for each post, it gives only 2 comment from all the fetched post.

**Current result:**

Post1:

1. Comment 1
2. comment 2

Post2:
No comment loaded in post 2 because it limits on whole.

**Expected:**

post1:

1. comment 1
2. comment 2

post2:

1. comment 1
2. comment 2

Comment: Try this `\App\Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->with(['comments' => function($q) {
    $q->take(2);
}])->get();` !!

Comment: I tried that but i gives the same result

Comment: Obvious question did post2 has comments ??

Comment: Yes id does have

Answer (score 0):

i have done something similar before try this instead

```
 public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id')->latest()->limit(4);
}
```

You can also add a global scope to the Post Model, so that it is always eager loading the 4 comments like so :

```
 static::addGlobalScope('comments', function ($builder){
        $builder->with('comments');
    });
```

so your boot method in your Post.php should look like this :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('comments', function ($builder){
        $builder->with('comments');
    });

}
```

therefore you can query like so :

```
$posts = \App\Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->where('user_posts.user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
```

UPDATE:

it does not work, when we query like this

```
$posts = \App\Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->where('user_posts.user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
```

because the limit is applied only once. check github issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835. However here's a possible solution https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, But it does the same thing. I have 5 post and and each one have comments but it load only 4 comments for all 5 corresponding posts...It should have loaded 4 comment for each 5 post

Comment: @SainishMomin hmmm, that's strange, what's the foreign key of the post on the comments table ?

Comment: post_id is the foreign key in comment table

Comment: @SainishMomin okay can you try to load 2 posts, something like this ==> App\Post::latest()->take(2)->get()  just to verify that it loads the comments correctly

Comment: Yes I tried loading for 2 post and it load correctly because first post have 2 comment and second also have 2 comment. So total 4 comment as we have limited in model

Comment: @SainishMomin please die and dump the results and put the snapshot here i.e using dd($posts)

Comment: Hi file is too long so I have uploaded on below link please check.
http://filenotepad.com/stackoverflowQUE

Comment: @SainishMomin okay i have seen it, is your "comments_count" getter working for each post ? if it is working load the comments there and lets see if it works. also try to eager load the comments without any constraint i.e remove  the "limit" constraint, lets verify that it loads all the comments for each posts. i believe you would find out where the error is coming from by trying these.

Comment: I already tried those methods but didn't seems working. However I tried below code and its working but it limits only one comment for each post.
in 


Post.php model


public function latestComment() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Comment')->latest();
    }

Comment: @SainishMomin i was able to reproduce your problem on my system. here is a github issue similar to yours https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835. after much digging i figured out that it worked on an application i built because i was eager loading the 'posts' as a relation to an activity table. Though there seem to be a solution here https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/. i would update my answer so as not to mislead others